# Will os.system(f"{var}") expose the variable (print/stdout)?

Tags: python, environment-variables, os.system

I have some security concerns regarding pythons `os.system`.
As I couldn't find an answer I would like to ask for your help.

So I have stored the username & password for my database as environment variables.
Then I want to start a server with a shell statement:

```
os.system(f"server --host 0.0.0.0 " f"{db_type}://{db_user}:{db_pw}@host")
```

I removed some parts of the statement as they are not relevant for this question.

**My question is:**
Will my variables `db_user` or `db_pw` get exposed somewhere? I am concerned that `os.system` will print or stdout the whole statement with the clear variables.
If so, is there a way to prevent it?

The code will run on an ec2/aws.
I know there are other ways to start a server but I am interested in this specific scenario.

Comment: I think so. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78734/why-shouldnt-someone-use-passwords-in-the-command-line `ps` show all commands from all users.

Comment: thanks @Aaron ! Do you know a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contents will be exposed. Not specifically on stdout/err, but you can see the contents.
Take the example

```py
password='secret'
os.system(f"echo {password} && sleep 1000")
```

This will start the command in a new subshell (as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system)). This process will now run, so it will be visible in the running process list. Start for example `top` or `htop` and search for that process.
That might display something like this:

[image]

There you can see the content of the `password` variable.
This is due to the fact, that first the complete string argument to `os.system` is evaluated and substituted. This string is then passed to `sh` to start a new subshell.

As a unix user can list the machines processes, it's never a good idea to pass secrets via cli arguments. Neither is passing via ENV-variables, as you could inspect the environment via `cat /proc/{$pid}/environ`.
The best way would be to pass the data via stdin to the subprocess.

Comment: Though `/proc/${pid}/environ` contain the secret, the permission `r--------` only allow the user (or root) to read it.